# ldap active directory PHP filter

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I want list members by some `CN`

I'm usign filter, it's work:

```
    $filter="(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=username)(memberOf=CN=g_jira,OU=Jira,OU=Groups,DC=office,DC=lamoda,DC=ru))";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"DC=office,DC=example,DC=ru",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    var_dump($info);
```

It's not work for me,  when I try to search user only by `CN`.

```
    $filter="(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=username)(memberOf=CN=g_jira*))";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"DC=office,DC=example,DC=ru",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    var_dump($info);
```

In `2` example I'm getting `count = 0`, what is worng with my example, how to provide only `CN` in filter and get some result as in `1` example ?

Comment: There is probably no `substring` index on the `memberOf` attribute on the user entry. Is there a reason you don't want to use the fully qualified group DN in the query filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot search for CN only where distinguished names are expected.

To achieve your goal, you must first find all groups that match your criteria:

`$filter = "(&(CN=g_jira*))";`

Once you get all the groups, you read their `member` attribute, perhaps uniquify the list of members so that you do not have duplicates and then query each of those users individually to get the users' data.

Alternatively (this might be faster depending on the number of *g_jira* groups), you search for all the groups as explained above and then perform searches as you originally intended, but for each group's full distinguished name. Then, you merge the returned lists of users.